# Find URLs of images by inspect elements in Firefox? (similar to Chrome?)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In Google Chrome, I right click in a webpage, and select

```
Inspect Elements -> Resources -> Frames -> (Search) -> Images
```

where I can see the URLs of the image files in the webpage. If I click the URLs, I will open a tab with the images. E.g.

[image]

How can I do the equivalent in Firefox? The "inspect elements" in Firefox has different menus than in Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: Press F12 -> "Network" tab on top-> "Images" tab on bottom -> press F5 to refresh the page -> and find the image (sprites.svg) you need. [Here's](http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/sprites.svg) the link I've just found for you. And sometimes it's easier to find it by pressing Ctrl+U (opens Source window) and finding it manually, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

(Yes, it's an old question, but someone may well come across it via search.)

Another way (besides the way indicated in a comment) is via 'Tools -> Page Info -> Media'. The 'Save As...' button can be used to download an image.

Comment: This is incredibly useful!  It is so easy... and finding the same image file/url in the inspector is so difficult that I never remember how.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, for opening Firefox DevTools:

- Press "F12" or,
- Right click anywhere in the screen and select "Inspect"

Then:

1. Go to "Network" tab.
2. Filter search by "Images".
3. Right click on the, and you'll see different images.

Here's a gif:

[image: How to find images using Firefox Developer Tools]

You can find more information here: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out:

1. Inspect Element
2. Find IMG class in the inspector
3. Copy Image Data URL
4. Paste into new Tab
5. Dowload or Copy image

Here is a GIF:

[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9CYh.gif)